# What is the meaning of Vtt

Tags: digital-logic

I was looking at the data sheet of a counter IC and the connection circuit diagram showed two connections: `Vbb` and `Vtt`

What do these mean? Is it related to the differential inputs the if supports?

Comment: Which counter???

Comment: @ironstein  If you are referring to a particular IC, which you've looked at, you should provide a link to the datasheet.

Answer (score 4):

Vbb - reference voltage for ECL used in single-ended input mode or for some types of termination. Usually you bypass to Vcc and tie the differential input that's not being used to Vbb, or tie inputs through back-to-back Schottky diodes to Vbb. Some devices have a Vbb output or it can be generated with an ECL gate.

Vtt - termination voltage- usually a separate supply at Vcc - 2.0V that allows termination with a single resistor rather than a divider.

Much more on ECL termination [here](http://ece.wpi.edu/analog/resources/and8020-d.pdf):

Edit: From your information regarding the counter part number and related [datasheet](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/MC100EP016A-D.PDF):

[image]

Vtt should be Vcc - 2.0V.

It might be easier to terminate with a Thevenin-equivalent resistor pair.

R1 || R2 = 50\$\Omega\$

\$\frac { R1}{(R1 + R2)} = \frac {V_{CC}-2}{V_{CC}}\$

(you can do the sums depending on your choice of Vcc)

Comment: So all I have to do is connect an external 3v supply to Vtt (assuming I am using Vcc 5V ) ???

Comment: @ironstein Did you read the document on ECL termination? I have to see a datasheet for the counter, that might not be the right answer. Also voltages are relative to Vcc in ECL.

Comment: The ic I am using is MC100EP016A and it has a Vcc range from 3 V to 3.6 V                         so accordingly ill have to use Vtt input of 1 V to 1.6 V  ???

Comment: If you use a separate supply, realize that it will have to *sink* rather than source current. A positive linear regulator will not do that.

Comment: So what am I supposed to connect at the Vtt terminal ???

Comment: As @ThePhoton says, you can use a negative regulator (there are a number of them) a positive regulator that *can* sink current (*some* can, but you have to read carefully, and if it does not say it will, assume it won't)- in either case plus one 50 ohm resistor per input, or just use the two Thevenin-equivalent resistors for every input that I suggested.

Answer (score 3):

Vtt is used in some ECL devices. It is typically 2 V below Vcc and is internally connected to the differential inputs of a receiver through a pair of resistors, ensuring the inputs are correctly terminated to a transmission line.